# getChild method in a module doesn't seem to refer to a child(?)

Tags: magento, module

I am using the Meanbee [Infinite Scroll](https://www.meanbee.com/magento-extensions/infinite-scroll.html) module in my project. I have it working for normal category product listings. But now I'm attempting to have it activate on my custom made module.

However I am stumped over line `68` in `Script.php`:

```
 66       return (
 67           $block !== false &&
 68           $block->getChild('toolbar') !== false && // <-- This line
 69           $this->_getPagerBlock() !== false &&
 70           $this->_getPagerBlock()->getCollection()
 71       );
```

There is no xml element that has attribute `name` of `toolbar`. Even in the normal category xml that is working. So what is `"toolbar"` refering to?

A `var_dump($block->getChild('toolbar'));` returns false on my page but not on the normal category product listing page.

My XML is as follows (for clarity):

```
        <block type="mynamespace/mymodule" name="mymodule.view" template="mynamespace/mymodule/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="toxicfox/giftfinder/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

And the core XML (which works with the Infinite Scroll module) is:

```
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

As you can see, neither block of XML has any element with an attribute `name` of `"toolbar"`. The only difference is line `1`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml()` method, the toolbar block is retrieved from the layout with the name that was indicated by the `setToolbarBlockName` action, then set as a child block of the products list with the `toolbar` alias.

In your case, the problem may be that the `$block` hasn't been output yet with `toHtml()`, so that it doesn't know yet about its `toolbar` child, or something of this kind (hard to say because the extension is commercial).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but if all I'm changing is the first line of the XML, shouldn't `$block->getChild('toolbar')` be returning true?

Comment: Just completed my answer